# Bootstrap in-line form not showing in-line

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Image of what is doing right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLCIB.png

```
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="navbar">
             <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="nav-collapse pull-right">
                    <div class="pull-left"><a href="./index.php?p=register" class="btn btn-success">Reg&iacute;strate</a></div>
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Con&eacute;ctate&nbsp;<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                            <form name="login" action="login.php" method="post" class="form-inline" style="max-width: none;">
                                <input name="user_name" class="input-medium" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" />
                                <input name="user_password" class="input-medium" type="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Con&eacute;ctate</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap, and the problem I have is that the form is showing horizontally, ignoring the class "form-inline". I have tried so many ways to try to do it without success. I bit of help would be appreciated. The form is inside a dropdown-menu, because I want to put the login-form when the user click the "Login" button in the navigation bar.

Comment: Kindly elaborate the question "Image of what is doing right now: http://i.imgur.com/3o4eJ4s.png" doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form` is flowing according to its parent size, and the problem is that the `div` is too small for it.

You must replace the default `width`. Setting `width: 430px !important` was enough for me.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;width: 430px !important;">
```

Comment: If I can ask something else here... How I can make the tooltip go to the left besides going to the right?

Comment: @OmaRPR If you're talking about the default browser tooltip, you can't AFAIK. However, there's a component for that inside Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: I fixed it, setting the dropdown-menu with the class pull-right... Like this:

    <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 430px !important; vertical-align: middle;">